# MySQL Statement Based On Field

Tags: mysql

I am looking to update a script that the original author no longer
supports but have got stuck on one of the changes I want to make.

Apologies if I have difficulty explaining as i'm sure this is quite basic.

I have a MySQL statement within a file as shown below but I now want to 
add an additional field to the database with a name of dformat.

Here is the current statement:

```
$SQL="SELECT `userid`, `score`, `summary`, `option`, DATE_FORMAT(`lastcheck`, '%d/%m/%y') AS `check`  FROM `".$dbpref."users` WHERE `active`='Y' AND `id`='".intval($_GET["user"])."'";
```

The part I wish to change is this bit:

```
DATE_FORMAT(`lastcheck`, '%d/%m/%y') AS `check`
```

What I want to be able to do is to check the new field dformat and where

dformat = 1 then DATE_FORMAT(`lastcheck`, '%d/%m/%y') AS `check`

but where

dformat = 2 then DATE_FORMAT(`lastcheck`, '%m/%d/%y') AS `check`

Is it possible to do the above from within the SQL statement itself rather than after?

I have tried to look for other examples but when applied to this then the errors begin
so am obviously not getting the statement right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do  it with `CASE` statment.

```
$SQL="SELECT `userid`, 
              `score`, 
            `summary`,
             `option`, 
             CASE WHEN dformat = 1 THEN DATE_FORMAT(lastcheck, '%d/%m/%y') 
                  WHEN  dformat = 2 then DATE_FORMAT(lastcheck, '%m/%d/%y') END AS `check`  
      FROM `".$dbpref."users` 
      WHERE `active`='Y' 
      AND `id`='".intval($_GET["user"])."'";
```

Comment: @amenadiel yeah :), its generally.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can do the following

```
$SQL="SELECT `userid`, `score`, `summary`, `option`, 
if(dformat=1 ,
DATE_FORMAT(`lastcheck`, '%d/%m/%y'), 
DATE_FORMAT(lastcheck, '%m/%d/%y')
) AS     `check`  FROM `".$dbpref."users` WHERE `active`='Y' 
AND  `id`='".intval($_GET["user"])."'";
```

that is, if dformat is a field on the table.

As a side note, I hope you aren't storing dates as text and you're using suitable types (timestamp or datetime) instead.